# Filtering dropdownlist based on previous dropdownlist id

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I have three dropdown lists - the second depends on the first and the third depends on the second. I have two different sql statements. The first is to get the data for the first dropdown list and the second and third dropdown lists depend on the second sql statements.

I am somewhat lost on how to configure the dropdown lists with the sql statements and properly filter based on the id.

I enabled `AutoPostBack` for the first dropdownlist.

Here is what i have:

```
<div>
            Section: <asp:DropDownList ID="FistDropDown" runat="server" DataSourceID="Sections" DataTextField="DisplayName" DataValueField="ID"></asp:DropDownList>
            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="Parent" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:MyConnection %>" SelectCommand="SELECT e.DisplayName,  e.ID , e.GUID
FROM Elements e
INNER JOIN ATable re
ON e.ID = re.ATableID
AND re.InstitutionsID = 1"></asp:SqlDataSource>
        </div>
        <br />
        <div style="margin-left: 65px">
            <asp:DropDownList ID="SecondDropDown" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" DataSourceID="FirstChild" DataTextField="DisplayName" DataValueField="ID"></asp:DropDownList>
            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="FirstChild" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:MyConnection %>" SelectCommand="SELECT e.DisplayName,  e.ID , e.GUID
FROM Elements e
INNER JOIN ATableMap em
ON e.ID = em.KnowsATableID
WHERE em.ATableID = "></asp:SqlDataSource>
        </div>
        <br />
        <div style="margin-left: 75px">
             <asp:DropDownList ID="ThirdDropDown" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
        </div>
```

Comment: That is *not* ASP.NET MVC...

Comment: @PatryCwiek i have the project set up as Asp.net mvc - even though i might not be using it that way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems you are expecting the data on same page.
you must firstly enter the value from 1st dropdown then you will be able to do the rest try same for 2nd drplist

Comment: How can i get my sql statement for 2nd drplist to fill based on the id form the 1st drplist?

Comment: this can be done if you are first saving the data from the first dropdown or if you store the data in some parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use "SelectParameters" in your SqlDataSource and combine it with "ControlParameter" to connect the value of the first drop down to a value in the second query. It'll be something like:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="FirstChild" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:MyConnection %>" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT e.DisplayName,  e.ID , e.GUID
                   FROM Elements e
                   INNER JOIN ATableMap em
                   ON e.ID = em.KnowsATableID
                   WHERE em.ATableID = ?">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="FirstDropDown" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Name="ID" Type="Int32" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Handle the SelectedIndexChanged event on the first drop down and invoke SecondDropDown.DataBind() to cause the query to execute and populate the drop down.